# rails swtiching to rspec from default test unit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a rails 4 app. I have no tests at the moment, but when I created the app I didn't skip the default `test unit` so there are some empty test files (and other default settings) in my app.

Now I would like to use `rspec` + `capybara`, but don't know what the necessary extra steps are to properly install those and make sure the testing will work fine. I saw some answers on stackoverflow but thoose were pretty old.

As far as I know the installation looks like this if test unit is skipped on creation:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara'
end
```

then

```
rails g rspec:install
```

Can sby tell me what the extra steps are?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow these steps:

**add code to your_app/config/application.rb file:**

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework :rspec
end
```

**add below code to your_app's Gemfile:**

```
group :test, :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
end
```

save it, and run `bundle install` to install rspec gem

**Initialize the spec/ directory**

```
rails generate rspec:install
```

**Use the rspec command to run your specs:**

```
bundle exec rspec
```

Hopefully it helps.

Comment: Mohammad, pls read my question again. I can't create a new app. I'd like to add to an existing one.

Comment: @SzilardMagyar no problem. Then add edit you existing app configuration file like above. It will work

Comment: Should I delete some old files?